# Angular 6 Server Side Rendering - 502 BAD GATEWAY NGINX for new project folder

Tags: angular, nginx, server-side-rendering, sap-commerce-cloud

we have SAP Hybris backoffice which hosts our server and angular code in JS-storefront folder ,

currently we have a project with server side rendering enabled and working perfectly with the help of manifest.json config as below

```
    "applications": [
{
  "name": "sampleproject", // name as per package.json
  "path": "SampleProject", // folder name under JS-storefront folder
  "enableSSR":true // flag to turn Server side rendering
      }
  ],
  "nodeVersion": "14"
}
```

For redesigning the old application, we have created a new folder (cloned the old folder) and tried replacing the config as above but post deployment in Backoffice, we are facing 502 BAD gateway issue while accessing the **yourproject/home** url but weirdly the the project is accessible if we add **/index.html** to the **yourproject/home**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNNRc.png)

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/b2f400d4c0414461a4bb7e115dccd779/63577f67a67347bf9f4765a5385ead33.html - steps followed for adding new folder

Comment: Adding current nginx config to your question can be a kind of helpful.

Comment: @IvanShatsky , we are trying to retrieve the same with help of SAP support , but the above info is all we got so far :-I